# Silverlight hangs on Prism's EventAggregator Subscribe method

Tags: silverlight, prism, eventaggregator

I am using Prism's event aggregator in Silverlight and am having a hard time with Subscribe.  When the code hits the Subscribe method it just hangs and never makes it to the next line of code.  If I break up the code, _eventAggregator.GetEvent() seems to return a valid instance of the event.  The code definitely hangs on "Subscribe".  What could I be doing wrong here?  The JobCompletedEvent is declared in another library (which is a dependency for this library).

```
    public void CallMeWhenTheJobIsDone(Action callback)
    {
        if (_jobIsRunning)
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<JobCompletedEvent>().Subscribe((e) => callback(), ThreadOption.UIThread); 
        else
            callback();
    }

    public class JobCompletedEvent: Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Events.CompositePresentationEvent<JobCompleted>
{ }
public class JobCompleted
{
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code used to publish the event and an example of the callback method you're using

Answer (score 0):

1) Why you using `if (_jobIsRunning)` ?? You calling `callback` in **any** case.

2) Prism will only bring you the event - and according to your question - Prism **IS** rising and passing the event to you - so it's not a Prism question - it seems that whatever called by `callback` is not working.

So we need to see more on what is called by `callback` and another thing: in Prism case you calling the `callback` on `ThreadOption.UIThread` ThreadPool so - double check if any other thread already lock the UI thread when you calling `callback`

Comment: The code I posted unnecessarily complex, there are reasons for the _jobIsRunning check but I should have provided an example that was more to the point.  Callback is also irrelevant (the code never gets that far, I could replace it with ()=>{} and I get the same problem). I think my EventAggregator has issues.  I am going to try and debug with the Prism source to see if I get any clues.

Comment: I take that back, putting ()=>{} fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that I should not have used an anonymous method in my subscribe.  Prism does not seem to support it.  Some are calling this a bug in Prism, I agree :)  Not only can you not use an anonymous method but the method must be public.

Some references I found googling

http://greenicicleblog.com/2010/04/28/prism-event-aggregator-more-leaky-than-it-seems/

[Execute same Prism Command from different ViewModels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610257/execute-same-prism-command-from-different-viewmodels)

I suspect this is in the Prism docs somewhere, I guess I just blew by it.  If I set keepSubscriberReferenceAlice it works with the private method or anonymous method (which does make some sense now that I think about it).  The funny thing is that in my sandbox project I cannot even compile with an anonymous method which uses privately scoped code.  My live project allows it to compile but fails at runtime.

Edit:
Yup, it is in the docs
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx
Big yellow box 2/3 of the way down the page.